# Average data for every four hours in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three fields in database `day, hour, value` every hour value will be stored in the database.
now i would like to take every four hours average value. for one day i need to get 6 rows with each row consisting four hours average value.

could you please help me regarding this.
[image: this is my table data]

[image: this is my result with your query] Its not correct right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  day
,       (hour - 1) DIV 4  /* or: (h + 3) DIV 4 */
,       avg(value)
from    YourTable
group by
        day
,       (hour - 1) DIV 4
```

Comment: if i take 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12... 24 as hour and run the query it is giving 14.000, 11.000, 12.000, 13.000 how it is?

Answer (score 0):

Exact the same as Andomar's just using the integer division operator:

```
select  day
,       hour div 4
,       avg(value)
from    YourTable
group by
        day
,       hour div 4
```